# Ambiguous aliases in Vite monorepo

Tags: typescript, vite, rollupjs, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

The problem occurs for Vite monorepo, `@` aliases are respected by TypeScript because of separate tsconfig files (can be visible in IDE) but aren't distinguished among the workspaces by Vite on build.

The project uses Yarn 1.x with workspaces, TypeScript 4.9, Vite 3.2, Lerna 6.4 (shouldn't affect the problem at this point)

Project structure is common for a monorepo:

```
packages/
  foo-bar/
    src/
      index.ts
    package.json
    tsconfig.json
    vite.config.ts
    yarn.lock
  foo-baz/
    (same as above)
  foo-shared/
    src/
      qux.ts
      quux.ts
    package.json
    tsconfig.json
    yarn.lock
lerna.json
package.json
tsconfig.json
yarn.lock
```

When one package (`foo-bar`) imports a module from another (`foo-shared`):

*packages/foo-bar/src/index.ts*:

```
import qux from `@foo/shared/qux';
```

Another package resolves local aliased imports to wrong package on build, because Vite is unaware of tsconfig aliases:

*packages/foo-shared/src/qux.ts*:

```
import quux from `@/quux'; // resolves to packages/foo-bar/src/quux.ts and errors
```

The error is something like:

> [vite:load-fallback] Could not load ...\packages\foo-bar\src/quux
> (imported by ../foo-shared/src/qux.ts): ENOENT: no such file or
> directory, open '...\packages\foo-bar\src\stores\quux' error during
> build:

`foo-shared` is currently a dummy package which isn't built standalone, only aliased and used on other packages.

*packages/foo-bar/vite.config.ts*:

```
  // ...
  export default defineConfig({
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        '@': path.join(__dirname, './src'),
        '@foo/shared': path.join(__dirname, '../foo-shared/src'),
      },
    },
    / * some irrelevant options */
  });
```

*packages/foo-bar/tsconfig.json* and *packages/foo-shared/tsconfig.json* are similar:

```
{
  "extends": "@vue/tsconfig/tsconfig.web.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"],
      "@foo/shared/*": ["../foo-shared/src/*"]
    },
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "../../node_modules/@types",
    ]
  },
  "include": [
     "src/**/*.ts",
     "src/**/*.d.ts",
     "src/**/*.vue"
   ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
}
```

I tried to replace `resolve.alias` with `vite-tsconfig-paths` plugin without success. It didn't affect the aliases at all out of the box, and I cannot be sure it's usable for this case.

How can Vite be configured to resolve paths that begin with "`@`" to different paths depending on the path of parent module?

Comment: "_packages/foo-bar/tsconfig.json and packages/foo-shared/tsconfig.json are similar:_" Are they just _similar_ (in which case, _show_ exactly how they are different), or are they exactly the same?

Comment: @user Some unrelated options are different in my case, but can be same with the same result, with '@foo/shared' path being unused in `@foo/shared` project

Answer (score 1):

From [the Vite docs on the the `resolve.alias` option](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#resolve-alias):

> Will be passed to `@rollup/plugin-alias` as its [entries option](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/alias#entries). Can either be an object, or an array of `{ find, replacement, customResolver }` pairs.

Unfortunately, at the time of this writing, the readme for rollup's resolve-alias plugin is... sparse:

> Type: `Function | Object`
> Default: `null`
>
> Instructs the plugin to use an alternative resolving algorithm, rather than the Rollup's resolver. Please refer to the [Rollup documentation](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#resolveid) for more information about the `resolveId` hook. For a detailed example, see: [Custom Resolvers](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/blob/master/packages/alias/README.md#custom-resolvers).

And the "detailed example" of a `customResolver` being referred to is not instructive at all if you actually want to know how to write one instead of using another mostly-pre-built one (one is left wondering what a `resolveId` hook is, and how it is relevant. For reference, I'm looking at the docs for v4.0.3. Hopefully they'll be better in the future)

Its type declaration file helps fill in the blanks. You can find it here: https://github.com/rollup/plugins/blob/master/packages/alias/types/index.d.ts, where you'll see something like:

> ```
> import type { Plugin, PluginHooks } from 'rollup';
>
> type MapToFunction<T> = T extends Function ? T : never;
>
> export type ResolverFunction = MapToFunction<PluginHooks['resolveId']>;
>
> export interface ResolverObject {
>   buildStart?: PluginHooks['buildStart'];
>   resolveId: ResolverFunction;
> }
>
> export interface Alias {
>   find: string | RegExp;
>   replacement: string;
>   customResolver?: ResolverFunction | ResolverObject | null;
> }
>
> export interface RollupAliasOptions {
>   /** blah blah not relevant for vite.js */
>   customResolver?: /* blah blah not relevant for vite.js */;
>
>   /**
>    * Specifies an `Object`, or an `Array` of `Object`,
>    * which defines aliases used to replace values in `import` or `require` statements.
>    * With either format, the order of the entries is important,
>    * in that the first defined rules are applied first.
>    */
>   entries?: readonly Alias[] | { [find: string]: string };
> }
> ```

In particular, that last part of the doc comment for `RollupAliasOptions#entries` is important. I'll wager you can resolve your issue by reordering your `resolve.alias` entries in your vite.config.js:

```js
alias: {
  '@foo/shared': path.join(__dirname, '../foo-shared/src'), // moved to be first
  '@': path.join(__dirname, './src'),
}
```

Now, if that doesn't work, or you find yourself in the future wanting to do anything where that doesn't suffice, you can write a custom resolver (see how the `Alias` type has a `customResolver` field?). This should answer your ending question: "*How can Vite be configured to resolve paths that begin with "`@`" to different paths depending on the path of parent module?*"

For that, you can see the linked docs in the rollup/plugin-alias docs: https://rollupjs.org/plugin-development/#resolveid. Here's a bit of relevant excerpt from the docs (**in particular, note the `importer` parameter**):

> |  |  |
> | --- | --- |
> | Type: | `ResolveIdHook` |
> | Kind: | async, first |
> | Previous: | [`buildStart`](https://rollupjs.org/plugin-development#buildstart) if we are resolving an entry point, [`moduleParsed`](https://rollupjs.org/plugin-development#moduleparsed) if we are resolving an import, or as fallback for [`resolveDynamicImport`](https://rollupjs.org/plugin-development#resolvedynamicimport). Additionally, this hook can be triggered during the build phase from plugin hooks by calling [`this.emitFile`](https://rollupjs.org/plugin-development#this-emitfile) to emit an entry point or at any time by calling [`this.resolve`](https://rollupjs.org/plugin-development#this-resolve) to manually resolve an id |
> | Next: | [`load`](https://rollupjs.org/plugin-development#load) if the resolved id has not yet been loaded, otherwise [`buildEnd`](https://rollupjs.org/plugin-development#buildend) |
>
> ```js
> type ResolveIdHook = (
>   source: string,
>   importer: string | undefined,
>   options: {
>       assertions: Record<string, string>;
>       custom?: { [plugin: string]: any };
>       isEntry: boolean;
>   }
> ) => ResolveIdResult;
>
> type ResolveIdResult = string | null | false | PartialResolvedId;
>
> interface PartialResolvedId {
>   id: string;
>   external?: boolean | 'absolute' | 'relative';
>   assertions?: Record<string, string> | null;
>   meta?: { [plugin: string]: any } | null;
>   moduleSideEffects?: boolean | 'no-treeshake' | null;
>   resolvedBy?: string | null;
>   syntheticNamedExports?: boolean | string | null;
> }
> ```
>
> Defines a custom resolver. A resolver can be useful for e.g. locating third-party dependencies. Here `source` is the importee exactly as it is written in the import statement, i.e. for
>
> ```js
> import { foo } from '../bar.js';
> ```
>
> the source will be `"../bar.js"`.
>
> The `importer` is the fully resolved id of the importing module. When resolving entry points, importer will usually be `undefined`. An exception here are entry points generated via [`this.emitFile`](https://rollupjs.org/plugin-development#this-emitfile) as here, you can provide an `importer` argument.
>
> [...]
>
> Returning `null` defers to other `resolveId` functions and eventually the default resolution behavior. Returning `false` signals that `source` should be treated as an external module and not included in the bundle. If this happens for a relative import, the id will be renormalized the same way as when the `external` option is used.
>
> [...]

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. This doesn't solve the problem but sheds some light. This looks like a common problem, I was hoping there's a ready to use solution. Unfortunately, customResolver can bring more problems because it should mimic Vite default resolver config and add custom behavior to it. Currently one of possible options that I see is to fork/extend Rollup alias plugin (which is quite small) and patch resolveId

Comment: @EstusFlask So you got the same result after switching the order of the alias definitions? Do you mind also answering my question comment under the question post?

Comment: The order of aliases doesn't matter in this case because in this case there's only one '@' alias entry, it refers to packages/foo-bar/src/ inside `@foo/shared` when it's imported inside `@foo/bar`. It could be expected that duplicate entries may work like `[{ find: '@', replace: '...foo-bar...'}, { find: '@', replace: '...foo-shared...'}]`, but they don't, when an alias fails to resolve, it doesn't falls back to another one, so only the first `@` in the list is applied

Comment: @EstusFlask sorry if this comes off as annoying, but I can't tell from your response: did you actually try it? Or are you just assuming what will happen?

Comment: I tried this but it was evident that it's not supposed to work, `'@foo/shared': path.join(__dirname, '../foo-shared/src'), '@': path.join(__dirname, './src')` entries contain no information for a resolver to resolve `@` to packages/foo-shared/src because __dirname is packages/foo-bar when `@foo/bar` project is built. My current workaround was to replace `@` paths with `@foo/shared` inside foo-shared, it's workable but a PITA for maintenance