# How to correctly setup a mono repo with yarn workspaces, vue3, typescript and vite

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite, yarn-workspaces

I'm using yarn workspaces for a couple of months now but i'm running into errors when trying to build stuff using `yarn build` which executes. Which executes `vue-tsc --noEmit && vite build`

the vue-tsc part fails sometimes after making small irrelevant changes. I guess this has to do with a typing error because sometimes when i fix a typing error i can continue. But it's never clear which error in what file.

the `vite build` always runs correctly when run seperately.

```
/home/projects/my-project/node_modules/vue-tsc/bin/vue-tsc.js:53
                        throw err;
                        ^

Error: Debug Failure. False expression: Paths must either both be absolute or both be relative
    at getRelativePathFromDirectory (/home/projects/my-project/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js:5717:9)
    at relativeToBuildInfo (/home/projects/my-project/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js:117152:38)
    at convertToReusableDiagnosticRelatedInformation (/home/projects/my-project/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js:117237:18)
    at /home/projects/my-project/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js:117223:20
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at convertToReusableDiagnostics (/home/projects/my-project/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js:117222:22)
    at getBuildInfo2 (/home/projects/my-project/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js:117099:11)
    at newProgram.getBuildInfo (/home/projects/my-project/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js:117309:41)
    at Object.getBuildInfo (/home/projects/my-project/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:116651:70)
    at emitBuildInfo (/home/projects/my-project/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:109453:30)
```

This is my setup:

- api
- vue-shared
- app-1
- app-2
- app-3

Root package.json

```json
{
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": [
    "vue-shared",
    "app1",
    "app2",
    "app3"
  ],
  "version": "0.10.2"
}
```

all apps have a dependency on vue-shared.

I use a lot of imports from each app to the vue-shared they look like this

```
import { useScopedTranslations } from "vue-shared/composables/useScopedTranslations";
```

And there are some imports from vue-shared to the app that's currently using the vue-shared import like this:

```
import { useAuthorisationStore } from "@/modules/authorisation/store";
```

for example: app1 can use a component from vue-shared that uses in this case the authorisation store from app1. If app2 imports the exact same component, since I use the @ alias. It uses the authorisation store from app2. etc.

Everything works fine when running `yarn dev` in each app. But when I run `yarn build` in the root folder I get the error message above.

ts config app

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "target": "esnext",
        "useDefineForClassFields": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "composite": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "strict": true,
        "jsx": "preserve",
        "sourceMap": false,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "lib": [
            "esnext",
            "dom"
        ],
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "types": [
            "node",
            "vuetify"
        ],
        "paths": {
            "@/*": [
                "src/*"
            ]
        }
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*.ts",
        "src/**/*.d.ts",
        "src/**/*.tsx",
        "src/**/*.vue",
        "vite.config.ts"
    ]
}
```

After each successfull build, a `tsconfig.tsbuildinfo` is generated. When this exists sometimes an error doesn't happen which does when this file is not present.
I'm not sure that i don't have type errors, I think I do have them but that's not the issue. The issue is that I don't know them and where they are. I only get a cryptic message.

I hope someone can verify my setup, and tell me if there's something wrong with that (I guess so, I've never had this issues without yarn workspaces). Or if there's a way to get more information about the error.

**Update**
When installing vue-tsc and typescript globally and then you run  `vue-tsc --noEmit` yourself. You do get the non cryptic errors. But why?

```
src/modules/member/views/ViewProgramMemberCreate.vue:92:22 - error TS18048: '__VLS_ctx.form.member.name' is possibly 'undefined'.

92             v-model="form.member.name.firstName"
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/modules/member/views/ViewProgramMemberCreate.vue:98:22 - error TS18048: '__VLS_ctx.form.member.name' is possibly 'undefined'.

98             v-model="form.member.name.insertion"
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/modules/member/views/ViewProgramMemberCreate.vue:104:22 - error TS18048: '__VLS_ctx.form.member.name' is possibly 'undefined'.

104             v-model="form.member.name.lastName"
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

After resolving this, the error from above is gone, this one:

```
/home/projects/my-project/node_modules/vue-tsc/bin/vue-tsc.js:53
                        throw err;
                        ^

Error: Debug Failure. False expression: Paths must either both be absolute or both be relative
...
...
```

Comment: " that's currently using the vue-shared import like this:" - it's unclear what's the meaning of this. There's no mention of vue-shared in this import. How is it related?

Comment: @EstusFlask vue-shared is one of my folder/yarn workspaces with my own shared components.
My intention there is to tell that app1 can use a component from vue-shared that uses in this case the authorisation store from app1. If app2 imports the exact same file, since i use the @ alias. It uses the authorisation store from app2.

Comment: `import ... from "@/modules/authorisation/store"` is in shared, then share is imported in app1 and app2, correct? Had a similar case, I didn't get this error in my setup but it's wrong by design. You will get unresolved import in ide when developing shared at least. I'd suggest to use some kind of DI, depends on your case how it needs to be done. Since auth is generally similar in the apps, maybe auth store belongs to shared, and you won't have this problem at all

Comment: I agree that it's a bit weird. But when building app1, and it's using some shared component that uses something from app1 which isn't present i could get an error.

The main problem is that my error is cryptic. I'm able after searching a long time to fix it. And I now know that vsCode can show those errors if i open 1 file after another. And the errors i'm getting at this moment have nothing to do with shared.

Some other reason i can not not do an import in shared from app1. is because i have a route builder in shared that's imported in each app to build all the routes so I need @/files

Comment: As said, I had a similar case, and that's the case for DI. In one shared module you can do `export let useAuthStore; export function setAuthStore(storeFn) { useAuthStore = storeFn }`, then setAuthStore can be used during app init. As for route builder, can be something like `export function createRouteDefs(appRoutes) { return { ...commonRoutes, ...appRoutes }`. And so on. Can't say why the error is there, it's supposed to depend on your setup and the way the packages interoperate.

Comment: In my case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75403735 shared prj is virtual and aliased in other prjs because it's not supposed to be bundled on its own, this likely makes the difference. In this case `@` aliases worked without errors, just not the way I wanted.

Comment: I noticed that deleting the created file `tsconfig.tsbuildinfo` prevents the error from `vue-tsc --noEmit`