Vue project path aliasing issues with Vite when npm link
I'm currently having some issues using project A in project B.
From project A's directory I ran:
npm link

From project B's directory I ran:
npm link rc-webcomponents

In project B's main.js I added:
import 'rc-webcomponents'

but when I run npm run dev in project B, I end up with the error:
Error: The following dependencies are imported but could not be resolved:

  @/polyfill (imported by M:/Dev/RC-WebComponents/src/index.ts)
  @/sass/reset.scss (imported by M:/Dev/RC-WebComponents/src/index.ts)
  @/plugins/rcwc (imported by M:/Dev/RC-WebComponents/src/index.ts)
  @/composables/RcwcObject (imported by M:/Dev/RC-WebComponents/src/index.ts)
  @/utils/relativeDate (imported by M:/Dev/RC-WebComponents/src/index.ts)
  @/locales (imported by M:/Dev/RC-WebComponents/src/index.ts)
  @/composables/customHtmlElement (imported by M:/Dev/RC-WebComponents/src/index.ts)

Are they installed?
    at file:///M:/Dev/localtests/my-vue-app3/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-mCdpKltl.js:50346:15
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async file:///M:/Dev/localtests/my-vue-app3/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-mCdpKltl.js:49851:26

Based on my understanding the issue has to do with vite path aliasing.
In my vite.config.mts I have:
export function defineSharedConfig(cfg:UserConfig): UserConfig {
    return defineConfig(
        {
            resolve: {
                ...(cfg.resolve || {}),
                alias: {
                    "@": fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url)),
                    vue: fileURLToPath(new URL("node_modules/@vue/compat", import.meta.url)),
                    "~rc-webcomponents": fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url)),
                    "~vue2-datepicker": fileURLToPath(new URL("node_modules/vue2-datepicker", import.meta.url)),
                    ...(cfg.resolve?.alias || {}),
                },
            },
    }

}

but based on the thread: `Vue3 - Vite` project alias src to @ not working
I should try and have it like:
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from "url";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: [
      { find: '@', replacement: fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)) },
      { find: '@assets', replacement: fileURLToPath(new URL('./src/shared/assets', import.meta.url)) },
      { find: '@cmp', replacement: fileURLToPath(new URL('./src/shared/cmp', import.meta.url)) },
      { find: '@stores', replacement: fileURLToPath(new URL('./src/shared/stores', import.meta.url)) },
      { find: '@use', replacement: fileURLToPath(new URL('./src/shared/use', import.meta.url)) },
    ],
  },
});

so I updated mine to look something like:
alias: [
                    { find: '@', replacement: fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)) },
                    { find: 'vue', replacement: fileURLToPath(new URL('node_modules/@vue/compat', import.meta.url)) },
                    { find: '~rc-webcomponents', replacement: fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)) },
                    { find: '~vue2-datepicker', replacement: fileURLToPath(new URL('node_modules/vue2-datepicker', import.meta.url)) },
                ],

but I'm still getting the same errors

The problem is that the package you linked wasn't built. Was there a reason for this, e.g. to get hot reload in both? Looks like the same problem, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75403735 , and a workaround was to replace @ with other alias in dependency packages. I don't remember exactly the alternatives, I believe it's creating a plugin that wraps around alias plugin and checks a combo of importer and importee somehow https://github.com/rollup/plugins/blob/master/packages/alias/src/index.ts#L86

You mean the first project isn't built? I did run npm build from the first project path though

I am hoping I don't have to manually go in the project to replace every single @, because there are a lot of them..

But you do aliases to /src that belongs to rc-webcomponents in B, right? If you use built RC-WebComponents, it's unclear why RC-WebComponents/src is mentioned in project B at all. In regular situation RC-WebComponents/dist/index.js (or whatever the entry point is) would be imported when you do import 'rc-webcomponents'. The replacing is solved with @/ global replace, no problems are generally expected because the pattern is unlikely to occur somewhere else, but you can surely check the list before replacing

I'm running in dev and not for production, maybe that could be the reason?

Dev server and builder work very differently in Vite. If one works and other doesn't, that's the case then

I think you should using relative or absolute path after npm link
